# Hibernate Many-to-Many mapping not working correctly on insert

Tags: c#, .net, sql, nhibernate

I have inherited a Spring+NHibernate c# app that we are doing a major overhaul on (and I'm fairly new to NHibernate).  The user/role set up in the database was less than optimal so I'm rewriting it since part of the project was adding new functionality anyway.  However, the translation into NHibernate isn't working correctly.  Here's the relevant parts of my setup:

Database:
3 tables; USERS, ROLES and USERS_XREF_ROLES (which is the join/bridge table)

User.hbm.xml:

```
<set name="Roles" table="[USERS_XREF_ROLES]" lazy="false" order-by="[FK_ROLES] asc" cascade="all">
    <key column="[FK_USERS]" />
    <many-to-many class="UserRole" column="[FK_ROLES]" />
</set>
```

UserRole.hbm.xml:

```
<set name="Users" inverse="true" table="[USERS_XREF_ROLES]" lazy="false" >
    <key column="[FK_ROLES]" />
    <many-to-many class="User" column="[FK_USERS]" />
</set>
```

Also note, there wasn't originally a set "Users" in the UserRole class; I had added it due to adding the bridge/join table and another post on SO that mentioned using a reverse set for bridge/join tables.  All SELECTs were working fine.  I went through multiple users and tested the permissions they should have.  However, when I tried to create a new user, it was obviously trying to insert into ROLES as well:

Error: Hibernate operation: could not insert: [UserRole][SQL: INSERT INTO [ROLES] ([VALUE]) VALUES (?); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()]; uncategorized DataException for SQL [INSERT INTO [ROLES] ([VALUE]) VALUES (?); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()]; ErrorCode []; Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'NAME', table 'ROLES'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.

A new user should obviously generate an INSERT into USERS and USERS_XREF_ROLES, but NOT ROLES.  So, what am I doing incorrectly here?  Thanks.

UPDATE:  I'm trying to make my question clearer.  My big problem is that all the examples I've ever found show inserting BOTH of the related objects into each respective table and into the join table.  I want to be able to add a User with an EXISTING Role.  I don't ever want an insert to occur in the ROLES table when creating a User.  Creating a User should always insert ONE record into USERS and one or more records into USERS_XREF_ROLES, but NEVER into ROLES because the user will always be assigned to existing roles.  I hope this is clearer.  I have yet to find an example that shows this and this must be a pretty common thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

> A new user should obviously generate an INSERT into USERS and USERS_XREF_ROLES, but NOT ROLES. So, what am I doing incorrectly here? Thanks.

This statement confuses me and I may just be misunderstanding but if USERS_XREF_ROLES is a bridge table then why would an INSERT into USERS necessitate an insert into the bridge table? It is possible a user may exist with no roles assigned is it not? With that in mind I'd expect that the problem isn't with the nHibernate mapping but rather the way your c# objects are being instantiated. Perhaps an unbound Role class is being created with the instantiation of the User class?

Comment: You are correct -- a record can exist in the USERS table without a corresponding record in the USERS_XREF_ROLES table. However, the business requirement is that all users must be assigned to at least one role.  My assumption was that NHibernate handles all of the insert logic and that it's all configurable through the XML.  I don't have a class for the bridge table (and that's the correct handling?) so how do I ensure a record gets inserted into USERS and USERS_XREF_ROLES? I think that's really what I'm not understanding here.

Comment: I don't know that such a requirement can be enforced by nHibernate due to the fact that it would have to know some default role to assign a user to. My recommendation would be that any such requirements be enforced by your data models in your c# code. A database trigger may work as well but I have a personal preference against these.

Comment: Yes, no db trigger for me, either.  So, what you're saying is that if I declare cascade="all" with the way I have it set up, it will attempt to insert a record into all 3 tables?  It seems that this would be an extraordinarily common situation which makes me think there should be a pretty common, straight-forward solution.  Yet, I'm really not finding much through google. Since I'm rewriting this anyway, I'm pretty open to different solutions.

Comment: I think I still may not be fully understanding you. If you always want a new User to be assigned to some role your choices are yes, either an insert must be generated for all three tables, or you must add an existing nHibernate bound Role object to the User class's role collection. (Part of my confusion may clear up if you show me the basic structure of your User and Role classes along with the code you're using to create a new User.)

Comment: Sorry, I got pulled away into another project.  I've updated my original question and hope my question is more clear now.